# How to add literal values (arbitrary values) to grep -Ff

Tags: grep

I used this code to filter out the results of a `find` command:

```
grep -Ff /path/to/file
```

Now, I want to add arbitrary values to that `grep` command.

In other words, I want to say, hey grep, use fixed patterns, and load your patterns from this file, and *here are these static patterns that are not in that file*.

How can I do that?

**P.S. context**: I asked [Can I filter out the find result based on lines of another file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763551/can-i-filter-out-the-find-result-based-on-lines-of-another-file), and now I want to filter the find either based on the entries in my `Dependencies` file, or if they are `Infra` or `Base`. But I can't add `Infra` and `Base` to the `Dependencies` file. That file is only for modules.

Comment: Hi! this is literally documented in the GNU `grep` man page where you find the description of `-f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns that `grep` uses are the collection of patterns read from all files specified with `-f` together with all separate patterns specified with `-e`.

If you want to add a single pattern `pattern` to your command:

```bash
grep -F -f /path/to/file -e 'pattern'
```

Both the `-f` and the `-e` option may be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subshell to pass you input pattern (collections) to grep. for example if your pattern file includes the lines:

```
$ cat pattern.txt
foo
bar
```

and you also want to searcch for baz (your fixed pattern) at the same time, then try:

```
$ grep -f <(echo baz; cat pattern.txt) infile.txt
```